# Click to add and resize element with Interact.js in on motion. Cannot start correct resize event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web, interact.js

Trying to add a new element (.item) on mousedown in .container. I would like the item to resize directly on add so you can add + resize in one motion and then release mouse.

Any ideas if that is possible? Trying to fire hold after element is added but that does not make it happen.

I need some serious help with this...would be awesome to make this work.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/kz12gwz9/41/

Resizing on added items work but there are problems when click->drag to add. The event are missing some vital data.

This works OK but there are multiple issues.

- `event.rect` is missing when triggering `move` event. L39-63
- can't stop the move event L37
- Have not be able to start resize by some other event than move! L90-103
- Must use modified version av interact.js found here https://rawgit.com/emilkarl/interact.js/fix--my-start-pointers/dist/interact.js

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container {
  border: 2px solid red;
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  position: relative;
}

.item {
  height: 20px;
  min-width: 20px;
  background-color: rgba(blue,0.5);
  position: absolute;
  &[resizing=true] {
    background-color: rgba(green,0.6);
  }
}
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
var itemWidth = 20;

var startResize = function(e) {
  console.log('startResize!');
  var interaction = e.interaction;

  if (interaction.interacting()) {
    return;
  }

  interaction.start({
      name: 'resize'
    },
    e.interactable,
    e.currentTarget);
};

var resizable = function(element) {
  return interact(element).resizable({
    snap: {
      targets: [
        interact.createSnapGrid({
          x: itemWidth
        })
      ],
      range: Infinity
    },
    edges: {
      right: true
    },
    onstart: function(e) {
      e.target.setAttribute('resizing', true);
    },
    onend: function(e) {
      e.target.setAttribute('resizing', false);
      // @FIXME: This should remove the MOVE listener but it does not
      e.interactable.off('move');
    },
    onmove: function(e) {
      var target = e.target,
        x = (parseFloat(e.target.getAttribute('data-x')) || 0);
      y = (parseFloat(e.target.getAttribute('data-y')) || 0);
      // update the element's width
      // @TODO: THIS SHOULD CHHHANE!
      var newX = (e.clientX - x);
      target.style.width = newX + 'px';

      if(e.rect === undefined) {
        console.warning("e.rect missing!");
      } else {
          console.log("e.rect exist");
        console.log(e.rect);
      }
      // This is the correct way but with move.
      // e.rect is part of the resize events but they are IMPOSSIBLE TO TRIGGER
      /*
        target.style.width  = e.rect.width + 'px'; // update the element's width
        x += e.deltaRect.left; // translate when resizing from left edge
      */

      target.style.webkitTransform = target.style.transform =
        'translate(' + x + 'px, ' + y + 'px)';
    }
  });
};

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.item').each(function() {
    resizable(this);
  });

  $('.container').on('mousedown', '.item', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
  });

  $('.container').mousedown(function(e) {
    var $container = $(this);
    var $item = $('<div class="item"></div>');
    var $itemEl = $item.get(0);

    $item.attr('data-x', e.offsetX);
    $item.attr('data-y', e.offsetY);

    $item.css('transform', 'translate(' + e.offsetX + 'px,' + e.offsetY + 'px)');

    // Add item to container
    $container.append($item);

    interactable = resizable($item.get(0));
    interact($itemEl).on('move', function(event) {
      var interaction = event.interaction;
      console.log('new item move'); // This should occur one for new items
      if (interaction.interacting()) {
        return;
      }
      // This workouts but it sends wrong event in!
      // resize rect is missing!!
      interaction.start({
          name: 'resize',
        },
        interactable, // target Interactable
        $itemEl); // target Element
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: To use `event.rect`also specify `edges` when starting a resize action manually: https://github.com/taye/interact.js/issues/206

Comment: were you able to solve this issue? I am in same situation